# How to stop ipython from closing open file handles for failed excecution

Tags: python, io, ipython

I try to debug some IO code, however the file keeps closing during exceptions.

Using the following snipped

```
with open('test', 'w') as fid:
    fid.write('a')
    1/0

In [1]: %run test.py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
***/test.py in <module>()
      1 with open('test', 'w') as fid:
      2         fid.write('a')
----> 3         1/0

ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

In [2]: %debug
***/test.py(3)<module>()
      1 with open('test', 'w') as fid:
      2         fid.write('a')
----> 3         1/0

ipdb> fid.write('b')
*** ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

should Illustrate what I mean. I do realize that closing the file handle no matter what is kind of the point of the `file` contextmanager. However since the stacktrace is preserved by IPython (5.1) it should be possible to open the file at the same location - given that the file was not altered in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

It's supposed to. The usage of `with open(filename, access_mode, buffering) as var` is to [immediately close the file](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/errors.html#predefined-clean-up-actions) after all the statements are executed. From the Python Docs:

> After the statement is executed, the file f is always closed, ***even if a problem was encountered while processing the lines***. Other objects which provide predefined clean-up actions will indicate this in their documentation.

The emphasis is mine. So, you would have to open the file the old fashioned way:

```
file_name = open("test", "w")
# insert rest of statements here
file_name.close()
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain very well what I meant. I do now that's the point of the contextmanager, that's why I wan't to leave it in. However for debugging purposes its actually bad. My question is how can I reopen the file at the same location. I would assume its possible since all the information is safed within the stacktrace.